# Stack Overflow for Teams "Admin" hexagon not showing on comments

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

The "hexagon" that identifies administrators of a Stack Overflow Team (akin to a diamond on regular Q&A sites) is no longer showing next to comments made by the team administrator.

If I remember correctly, it used to show next to comments (and the moderator diamond does show next to comments), but I've noticed today that it does not show next to comments.

Is this intentional? If not, can it please be fixed?

Comment: It's never shown the hexagon on comments, but I don't remember if there was a reason for it.